# Multiple ID's on single button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**HTML + PHP**

```
<?php
  for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
?>

<input readonly class="copyTarget" id="copyTarget<?php echo $i; ?>" value="val<?php echo $i; ?>">

<span>
    val<?php echo $i; ?>
</span>

<button class="btn btn-primary" id="copyButton<?php echo $i; ?>"  onClick="reply_click(this.id, $('.copyTarget').attr('id'));">Copy</button>


<?php
  }
?>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
    function reply_click(clicked_id, target_id) {
        alert(clicked_id);
        alert(target_id);
    }
</script>
```

**What i want**

I want to get the both values for copyTarget and copyButton as per loop cycle. It means

If current value of `$i = 3`

then I want alert values like,

```
clicked_id = copyTarget3
target_id = copyButton3
```

**What i am currently getting is,**

If current value of
`$i = 3`

then I want alert values like,

```
clicked_id = copyTarget0
target_id = copyButton3
```

Its taking first value of ID(copyTarget) stored initially. I want current loop cycle value.

Any help would do

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why use JS in handler?

Try:

```
onClick="reply_click('copyButton<?php echo $i; ?>', 'copyTarget<?php echo $i; ?>')"
```

Also you should store id names (`copyButton` and `copyTarget`) in php variable, so you can change them in one place.

Comment: I didnt know this way. Now, i can use this at various places. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like below. However, I would go by Maxx's answer .. It really depends on what you plan to do with the rest of code etc.

```
<?php
  for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
?>

<div>
    <input readonly class="copyTarget" id="copyTarget<?php echo $i; ?>" value="val<?php echo $i; ?>">
    <span>
      val<?php echo $i; ?>
    </span>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" id="copyButton<?php echo $i; ?>"  onClick="reply_click(this)">Copy</button> 
</div>

<?php
  }
?>

<script>
function reply_click(btn) {
    var clicked_id = $(btn).attr('id');
    var target_id=$(btn).parent().find('span').html();

    alert(clicked_id);
    alert(target_id);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
<?php
 for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
 ?>

 <input readonly class="copyTarget" id="copyTarget<?php echo $i; ?>" value="val<?php echo $i; ?>">

 <span>
   val<?php echo $i; ?>
 </span>

 <button class="btn btn-primary" id="copyButton<?php echo $i; ?>"   onClick="reply_click(this.id);">Copy</button>


<?php
 }
?>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
function reply_click(clicked_id) {
    alert(clicked_id); //clicked id
    alert(clicked_id.split('copyButton').join('copyTarget')); // target id
}
</script>
```